# How to Drag and Drop from one div to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Can anybody help me

1. From the Products div when i drag the "iphone" it will go to the "Shopping Cart" but I don't want it to go "Other Cart".
2. From the Other div when i drag the "Lolcat Shirt" it will go to the "Other Cart" but I don't want it to go "Shopping Cart".

What i want to tell is Products elements wants to go the Shopping Cart and Other elements want to go the Other Cart

Please see my code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Shopping Cart Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }
        #products { float: left; width: 500px; margin-right: 2em; }
        #cart { width: 200px; float: left; margin-top: 1em; }
        #cart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("#catalog").accordion();

            $("#catalog li").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            });

            $("#cart ol").droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                    $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
                }
            }).sortable({
                items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
                sort: function() {
                    // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
                    // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="products">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>
        <div id="catalog">
            <h2><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h2>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>iPhone</li>
                    <li>iPod</li>
                    <li>iPad</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="products">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Other</h1>
        <div id="catalog">
            <h2><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h2>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Lolcat Shirt</li>
                    <li>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
                    <li>Buckit Shirt</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Other Cart</h1>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but I think what you mean is you want only other products to be added to the other cart and not let Products be added to the other cart?

In that case what you could do is uniquely identify both carts and both catalogs instead of having the same id for both eg:

```
...<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Other</h1>
       <div id="catalogO">...
```

and

```
...<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>
       <div id="catalogP">...
```

and to the same for the cart Ids.

Then have two draggable functions, one for each catalog eg:

```
$("#catalogP li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});

$("#catalogO li").draggable({
     appendTo: "body",
     helper: "clone"
});
```

Then add two droppable functions, one for each cart eg:

```
$("#cartP ol").droppable({
     activeClass: "ui-state-default",
     hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
     accept: "#catalogP li",
     drop: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
         $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
     }
 }).sortable({
     items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
     sort: function() {
         // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
         // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
         $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
     }
 });

 $("#cartO ol").droppable({
     activeClass: "ui-state-default",
     hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
     accept: "#catalogO li",
     drop: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
         $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
     }
 }).sortable({
     items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
     sort: function() {
         // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
         // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
         $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
     }
 });
```

Basically the important thing is to change the accept property of the droppable function to the draggable function's ID or class. This will only allow components with that ID to be dropped into the droppable component.

I am sure there are more efficient ways of doing this but changing the accept property is a good quick start to look at for solving your problem, that is if that was your problem, if not please specify more clearly. Thanx.

Comment: Sorry Pravin accidently submitted before I was finished writing. Also if you decide to go with the unique ids for the different divs, remember to adjust your css aswell.